# centering a button using css

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble centering my button and don't know why its not working.

here is the html and the CSS.

```css
.button {
  margin:auto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #00007f;
  border: 2px solid rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.59);
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: rgba(172, 172, 172, 0.55);
  font: bold 3em/100px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  box-shadow:0 4px 0 #ACACAC;
}

a.button {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="blabla.html" class="button"  style= "text-align: center"> Start Game</a>
```

Comment: why didn't you **google** this? 
it's the most frequently asked question in CSS, the very basic thing.

Answer (score 1):

On the **parent** that contains the button set

```
text-align: center;
```

Like:

```css
.button {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #00007f;
  border: 2px solid rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.59);
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  color: rgba(172, 172, 172, 0.55);
  font: bold 3em/100px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  box-shadow:0 4px 0 #ACACAC;
}

a.button {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* HELPER CLASSES:*/
.text-center{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<p class="text-center">
  <a href="blabla.html" class="button"> Start Game</a>
</p>
```

And remove width and height from your button - will make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

Centering inline elements and block elements are done differently.

In your case, you tried to use `margin: auto` which is for centering block elements, but you set the button to `inline-block`. Simply change the button to `display: block` and you're all done.

```css
.button {
  margin:auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #00007f;
  border: 2px solid rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.59);
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: rgba(172, 172, 172, 0.55);
  font: bold 3em/100px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  box-shadow:0 4px 0 #ACACAC;
}

a.button {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="blabla.html" class="button"  style= "text-align: center"> Start Game</a>
```

Comment: it's a bad idea to use `block`. It forces you to use a fixed width which just complicates designing. The button context should dictate the width.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan There is already a fixed size to that element. Why fight it? If this is the design, there is nothing wrong with keeping the anchor with that property. Design could have various constrains I am not aware of (for instance, all buttons must have a fixed size, due to inner consistency in design).